# Using Radio Buttons VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm making a game inside of PPT for work and I'm trying to get radio buttons to work. I want there to be three radio buttons and, depending on which one is clicked, an "advance slide" button will redirect the user to a different slide

Simplying it to a single radio button, it should be (psuedocode)

```
If radioButtonA.value = true then
GoToSlide (n)
End If
```

I can't even get it to work with a message box! Just to see that I am correctly pulling the boolean value from the radio button being clicked or not.

I've tried

```
If (ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("radioButton1").value = true) then
MsgBox("Plz work")
End if
```

^^ doesn't do anything

I've also tried

```
Dim radioBoolean as Boolean
radioBoolean = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).shapes("radioButton1").value 

if radioBoolean = true
MsgBox("Plz work")
end if
```

Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("radioButton1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = True

Radio buttons are named OptionButtonX so I'm assuming that you've renamed yours to radioButtonX.